# Does the mark end immediately or can immediate reaction prevent this?

Tags: dnd-4e, mark

Last game, during an encounter, a player which created a mark took a few to many hits and went below 0 hit-points. The bard used an immediate reaction to bring him back to the action, but for a split second the creator was unconscious, so the mark ended.

> A mark ends immediately when its creator dies or falls unconscious.

The players however disagreed with this and i was not 100% sure myself.

Was my interpretation of the rules correct? And if yes is there a way to keep the mark active even though a dive through 0 HP?

Comment: What is the trigger for the interrupt?

Comment: The trigger was one of the healers powers, i think something like one of four allies takes damage. i will look for the power and post it when i found it. its just gone take an hour or two..

Comment: The trigger was the the bard using 'Word of Life' so it was immediate reaction

Answer (score 4):

**You were right.**

Only an Interrupt can invalidate its trigger. The character that created the mark was unconscious for a split second.

Had the power been a Interrupt, they would be right.

Comment: of course he was not dead, in fact he just started to die, but in order to be dead he has to fail 3 saving rolls, however he was unconscious and i believe that qualifies to end the mark

Comment: what power was used on the marker?

Comment: The trigger was the the bard using 'Word of Life' so it was immediate reaction, my bad

Comment: edit the question, I edit my answer